# Reading the output of a terminal command in java with BufferedReader

Tags: java, terminal, ifconfig, output

Noobie at java just starting, would appreciate any help. So my code is this and for some reason I cant get the output to work..I ve been sitting at this for hours..

```
package askisi1;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

    try{

        String command = "ifconfig eth1 | grep -oP '[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}'";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        System.out.println("So far so good");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        }
        r.close();
        System.out.println("Continue..");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: This might be a bit duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159913/problem-reading-inputstream-from-java-process-runtime-getruntime-exec-or-pr

Comment: Have you run the command to make sure it produces output?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl i researched the question you posted prior to posting my question, but it seemed too complicated working with the thread and cause i haven't been familiar with ProcessBuilder. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @jozefg Yes, the command produces the correct output in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` needs some additional information to execute an Unix Command.

So, assuming my ethernet card is `lo0`:

```
String[] command = {
                    "/bin/sh",
                    "-c",
                    "ifconfig lo0 | grep -oP '[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}'"
            }; 
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
// following here your remaining unchanged code
```

This prints:

```
So far so good
127.0.0.1
Continue..
```