# Send input to nmap process

Tags: java, stdin, processbuilder, nmap

I'm attempting to send input to an nmap process running from a ProcessBuilder but I'm not seeing a response from the running nmap process. I've looked through the nmap source code and it accepts runtime interactive input from a TTY, so I have tried running it with `/bin/bash -c` in addition to directly with `/usr/bin/nmap`.

I have another thread that reads the stdout from nmap, [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159913/problem-reading-inputstream-from-java-process-runtime-getruntime-exec-or-pr). Here is my code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/nmap", "-v", "-sT", "192.168.1.1-40");
//ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "\"\"/usr/bin/nmap -v -sT 192.168.1.1-40\"\"");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = builder.start();
LogStreamReader lsr = new LogStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
Thread thread = new Thread(lsr, "LogStreamReader");
thread.start();

while(thread.isAlive()) {
    OutputStream stdin = proc.getOutputStream ();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
    System.out.println("Sending input to process...");
    writer.write("a");
    writer.close();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

nmap should respond to the `writer.write(a)` by printing out the percentage complete/ETA of the scan, but it doesn't.

I've also tried running the writer in a separate thread akin to the LogStreamReader thread, but still nothing...

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
I've been told nmap has an option `--stats-every` which does exactly what I need, so this is solved. I couldn't find a way to write to the tty that nmap uses though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nmap's runtime interaction is not taken from STDIN, but from the TTY (reference [this nmap-dev thread](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2012/q1/695)). I'm not a Java expert, but I don't think `ProcessBuilder` supports this kind of interaction.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried running it with a `Runtime.exec` and redirecting input to the tty with `</dev/tty` but that still doesn't work. I'll keep looking for other ways of interacting with the TTY.

Comment: `--stats-every` does exactly what I need so no need for writing to tty etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java library for running Nmap called Nmap4j. You may find that helpful. It is on sourceforge: nmap4j.sourceforge.net.